# Why my deploy to railway of a django project is getting a error?

Tags: django, deployment, railway

I am trying to do a deploy of a django project do railway and I am getting this error:

```
usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]

gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --log-file--
```

I don't know why is showing the argument --log-file--, because in my file is in the correct form --log-file -

Like this: `web: gunicorn agenda.wsgi --log-file -`

If someone have this error too, could help me?

I am expecting the railway deploy my website